# Why does my statement asking if two variables are equal not work?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, variables

```
Private Sub CommandButtonUndo_Click()

Dim Answer As Integer, LastRow As Variant, PreviousLastRow As Variant

LastRow = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
PreviousLastRow = Names("PreviousLastRow").Value

If PreviousLastRow = LastRow Then
    MsgBox "Can only undo Once"
    Else
    If LastRow > 1 Then
        Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Undo the Previous Input?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New Job")
            If Answer = vbYes Then
                Worksheets("DATA").Rows(LastRow).ClearContents
                Names("PreviousLastRow").Value = LastRow - 1
            End If   
    End If 
End If
End Sub
```

The idea of the code is to stop a user being able to click the undo button more than once. The specific part this is tripping me up is `If PreviousLastRow = LastRow Then` which just seems to be ignored and always follows the else path, even when I know the two variants are the same

Is this to do with the two numbers not being seen the same by the code?

Comment: Because you are resetting on every click before comparison.  use a module level variable and set the value after comparison.

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean sorry? I am using ```Names("PreviousLastRow").Value``` as an atempt to keep the number a persistant

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and inspected the values of PreviousLastRow and LastRow?  Or maybe set a breakpoint on the If statement in question?

Comment: Yes, I previously added ```MsgBox "PreviousLastRow " & PreviousLastRow & "LastRow " & LastRow``` directly before the If statement and they both say the same number but still ignore the statement. This lead me to think the code sees the numbers differently. The message box says "PreviousLastRow =10 LastRow 10" with one having the = and the other not which I don't understand

Comment: Did you also check the data type of both variables which you defrined as variant in the beginnig. If `lastrow` is `10` and of type integer during runtime and `PreviousLastRow`  is `"10"` and of type string the statement `PreviousLastRow = LastRow` is false.

Comment: If the variable corresponds to a row number, then make it a `Long` instead of a `Variant`... also that `Integer` is probably better as `VbMsgBoxResult`.

Comment: No I did not check the data type, what is the best way to do this? I think this is likely the issue though. I can make those changes but I don't think they will fix why the If statement is ignored?

Comment: I changed the variables to Long and the code does not run at all now, type mismatch, so the issue is definitely to do with the data type of the two. I don't know how to make them the same unfortunately

Comment: _""PreviousLastRow =10 LastRow 10" with one having the = and the other not which I don't understand"_ this seems to be worth investigating

Comment: The defined name returns a `String` including the `=`... so you need to strip out the `=` and then `CLng` the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Name.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.value) documentation:

> Returns or sets a **String** value that represents the formula that the name is defined to refer to.

`PreviousLastRow = Names("PreviousLastRow").Value`

This returns `=10`, so get rid of the `=` and `CLng` the result:

```
PreviousLastRow = Names("PreviousLastRow").Value
PreviousLastRow = Replace(PreviousLastRow, "=","")
PreviousLastrow = Clng(PreviousLastRow)
```

Comment: or simply PreviousLastRow = Evaluate(Names("PreviousLastRow").Value)

Comment: @HTH - yes that's another option - I left it longer to demonstrate what was happening.

Comment: Brilliant, stripping out the "=" sorted it out. The message box returns PreviousLastRow 10 LastRow 10 and the If statement works. Thank you!

Comment: PreviousLastRow = Evaluate(Names("PreviousLastRow").Value) this also works. Thank you!